# How to get the mouse "x" and "y" when I click in scala

Tags: scala, scalafx

Hello I'd like to know if there's a way to get the mouse x and y pos when I click, currently I have a  button that when clicked it shows up a textbox, and after you're done with the input youre prompted to click on a gridpane and it will draw a circle where the user clicked. If possible I'd like to keep java out of this, but it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

For any node you can process mouse events using code like:

```
node.onMousePressed = (me: MouseEvent) => {
  println(s"Mouse pressed at (${me.screenX}, ${me.screenY})")
}
```

And so on.